# How to force "power of 10" notation with siunitx?

Tags: siunitx

I want to force siunitx to display numbers in standard form (e.g., 1.23 x 10<sup>3</sup>) unless the number is between 0 and 10. How can I do this?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: I'm actually formatting numbers from a csv file using csvsimple, so I'm using \num{\myvalue}, where I don't know what \myvalue will be.

Comment: Use `\num{1.23e3}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply @daniel. I'm actually formatting numbers from a csv file using csvsimple, so I'm using `\num{\myvalue}`, where I don't know what `\myvalue` will be. How can I do it in this case?

Comment: @Henry: Can you edit your question with this new information, and add a MWE?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `\sisetup{scientific-notation = true}`. See page 25 of the [`siunitx`](https://ctan.org/pkg/siunitx?lang=en) manual for more options.